# Add widget dynamically from outside class (error)

Tags: python, kivy, widget, popup

I´m learning **kivy**, and it has passed 3 weeks since i face this **problem** without encounter a solution, so i hope any of u guys could **help** me, i would appreciate it.

I have a main file:

```
from app import MyProgramApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    winapp = MyProgramApp()
    winapp.run()
```

from where i start my app. Then i have a directory called "app", inside there is the following "**init**.py" file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.utils import QueryDict, rgba
from kivy.core.window import Window
from .view import MainWindow

Window.minimum_width = 500
Window.minimum_height = 650
Window.maximize()

class MyProgramApp(App):
    colors = QueryDict()
    colors.primary = rgba('#2D9CDB')
    colors.secondary = rgba('#16213E')
    colors.succes = rgba('#1FC98E')
    colors.warning = rgba('#F2C94C')
    colors.danger = rgba('#E85757')
    colors.grey_dark = rgba('#C4C4C4')
    colors.grey_light = rgba('#F5F5F5')
    colors.black = rgba('#A1A1A1')
    colors.white = rgba('#FFFFFF')

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()
```

Same folder app, i have the following "view.py".

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ToggleButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    username = StringProperty("Usuario")
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
    def on_press_home(self):
        self.ids.scrn_mngr.current = "scrn_home"

class ViewManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)

class NavTab(ToggleButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty('')
    icon = StringProperty('')
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
```

and finally for that folder i have "myprogram.kv"

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

#:import Home views.home.Home

<MainWindow>:
    spacing: dp(8)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: app.colors.white
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    # NAVIGATION BAR
    BoxLayout:
        id: nav_menu
        size_hint_x: .2
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_min_x: dp(100)
        # LOGO 
        BoxLayout:
            id: logo_nbox
            size_hint_y: .1
            size_hint_min_y: dp(70)
            padding: dp(16)
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: "right"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: dp(52)
                halign: "left"
                Label:
                    text: "COMPANY"
                    halign: "center"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                Label:
                    text: "COMPANY"
                    halign: "center"
                Label:
                    text: "Phrase"
                    halign: "center"
        # OPTIONS
        GridLayout:
            id: tabs_box
            cols: 1
            spacing: dp(4)
            size_hint_y: .5
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: app.colors.grey_dark
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: [self.size[0], dp(1)]
            NavTab:
                text: "Home"
                state: "down"
                on_press: root.on_press_home()
            
    # BODY
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_x: .8
        spacing: dp(8)
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: [dp(16), dp(8), dp(12), dp(8)]
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: app.colors.grey_light
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size              
        # SCREENS
        BoxLayout:
            ViewManager:
                id: scrn_mngr
            
<ViewManager>:
    Screen:
        name: "scrn_home"
        Home:
            id: home
                  
                
<NavTab>:
    background_normal: ""
    background_down: ""
    background_color: [0,0,0,0]
    group: "tabs"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(45)
    spacing: dp(4)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: [0,0,0,0] if self.state == "normal" else rgba("#E1F1FF")
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: [0,0,0,0] if self.state == "normal" else app.colors.primary
        Rectangle:
            pos: [self.pos[0]+self.size[0]-dp(1), self.pos[1]]
            size: [dp(8), self.size[1]]
    Label:
        halign: "left"
        valign: "middle"
        text: root.text
        color: app.colors.grey_dark if root.state == "normal" else app.colors.primary
```

Then i got another folder called "views" inside i have another folder called "home", inside home we encounter 3 files "**init**.py", "home.kv", "home.py". the first one "**init**.py" is the following.

```
from .home import Home
```

then we got "home.kv".

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

<Home>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        size_hint_y: .1
        text: "Other"
    Button:
        size_hint_y: .1
        text: "popup"
        on_press: root.open_popup()
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .8
        id: home_box

<SomePopup>:
    title: "SOME TITLE"
    title_align: "center"
    title_color: app.colors.primary
    size_hint: .25, .8
    size_hint_min_x: dp(200)
    pos_hint: {"x": .1, "top": .9}
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: [dp(0), dp(12), dp(0), dp(12)]
        Label:
            text: "Some text"
        Button:
            text: "create buttons on box"
            on_press: root.modify_home_box()
```

and finally and the problem that i´m facing is whit the following file "home.py"

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_file('views/home/home.kv')

class Home(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def open_popup(self):
        Factory.SomePopup().open()

class SomePopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
    
    def modify_home_box(self):
        my_app = App.get_running_app().root
        my_box = my_app.ids.home.ids.home_box
        custom_button = Button(
            text = "something"
        )
        my_box.add_widget(custom_button)
```

That i´m trying to do is actually modify "home_box" with is store on ids Home dictionary, i also try with ObjectProperty (but that gives and Attribute Error, since i only could read propertys but doesnt modify it), instance of a new Home class doesnt work... searching for current app in App appear doesnt work since Home is store i think on screenManager...

I need add a button or some widget to "home_box" from outside class "SomePopup". I also drop here a repository on github with the whole code. [github_repo](https://github.com/SaroCompany/KIVYTEST)

I don't know how to solve my issue, and i try with the resources available here on stack as well other net places... any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a very complicated path to the widget of interest. In your `modify_home_box()` method, try replacing:

```
    my_app = App.get_running_app().root
    my_box = my_app.ids.home.ids.home_box
```

with:

```
    my_app = App.get_running_app().root
    my_box = my_app.ids.scrn_mngr.ids.home.ids.home_box
```

Comment: That solve my problem, thx a lot... i just learn cuz u about finding the path to my widgets